# html div not allowed to go off page

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off, let me give you a little background. I am creating a responsive page using % for positioning my divs. It allows the user to drag and drop items wherever they please. The issue arises when the user places the object to near the edge of the page. When you resize the browser the images start to go off the page and get cut off.

```
    #div1 
    {
    overflow: hidden; 
    right: <?php variable>;
    bottom: <?php variable>;
    }

    #div2 
    {
    overflow: hidden; 
    left: <?php variable>;
    top: <?php variable>;
    }
```

What I would like to try and do is allow the percentage's to control the placement up until the edge of the page. Then I would like to hardcode the variables to something like 10px so it never goes of the page.

I thought of doing this in javascript(if statement('s)), but thought maybe there was a simpler way(css properties). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You can probably use CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). If I knew them a little better I'd try writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use javascript you need to have a separate function that triggers on browser resize:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //your code here
}
```

or if you are using the popular jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

is the same.

If you want to hardcode it with css use a @media query:

```
@media(max-width:767px) { /*or whatever you want to use to trigger the css that will be used after browser size fits your problem */
    .myImage {left:10px;top:10px;}
}
```

More info on what you can use with @media can be found here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

If you ask me I think that you will accomplish a much more solid solution using javascript and since I suspect you are using js to drag elements around just go with it for resizing and repositioning too.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I have a function which listens for the window resize, but the left, right, top, bottom were not in then function which may have something to do with it.

Comment: @RobinHood I'm not really familiar on how PHP interacts with this kind of events, but javascript is definately the way to go in this case - I would set left and top variables with js and than just update them in the resize function if needed. But than again - don't really know what your app is all about :)

Comment: @RobinHood - just create a function for setting top and left and than call it on load and on window resize.